# Generate nonce square client side but not through payment form

Tags: square-connect, square, nonce

Hey I'm making an application that gets card information through a magnetic reader and dont want to use the sq payment form to generate the nonce on the client side. Is there a way to generate the nonce client side. I know a hacky way to do it would be to autopopulate the form and submit it with the card data behind the scenes to generate the nonce, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. I tried looking online but I could only find the payment form as a solution. However, most posts saying that its only possible through the form are over a year old, so I have hope!

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way is through the payment form still mainly due to security reasons.